# Ideal settings for AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an application which hardly consumes 2-3% of CPU and Memory of the assigned Amazon RDS instance.

But periodically, when we do data processing, it requires a lot of CPU and we need to increase the instance size for that or else, it freezes.

Any idea how a problem of this kind can be tackled?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like [Aurora serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/#) would be what you need.

This way the scaling is handled for you.